# Disable transition on $state.go

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ionic-framework

I am using angularJS with ionic. When I do `$state.go('app.test')` the page opens with sliding from right to left. Is there any way to disable this transition? Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the next animation, before the `$state.go` statement you must call:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
    disableAnimate: true
});
```

[Here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) you have more information about the `$ionicHistory` service.